# How to supernet Class C IP address with isc-dhcp server?

Tags: dhcp, ip

Is this possible?

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.248.0 {
range 192.168.5.1 192.168.5.254;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the dynamic IP address pool size can be a subset of the overall sub-net declaration. Often that is how one sub-net can be used for both dynamic and static IP addresses.